# visual studio issue regarding textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (checkID.Text.Contains(li.ToString()))
            {
                string [] word = li.ToString().Split(' ');              
                string studentInfo = word[0];
                string studentInfo2 = word[1];
                TextBox2.Text = studentInfo + " " + studentInfo2;
            }
        }
```

so the listbox contains name surname and ID. If that list contains the ID that i want to find, the name and surname will show in TextBox2.Text. That problem is it nothing show up. any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your IDE and walking through the logic as it executes? Also what value do you get back when you call li.ToString()?

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Answer (score 3):

***ListItem*** is an object. I believe you want to check with either **ListItem.Text** or **ListItem.Value**.

```
if (checkID.Text.Contains(li.Text))
```

OR

```
if (checkID.Text.Contains(li.Value))
```